# Source maps for Compass plugins point to incorrect sass source location

Tags: compass-sass, compass, source-maps

My standalone project is built with Compass (1.0.3) and some Compass extensions. The source maps generated point to the extensions' sass source files, but for some reason they're pointing to eg.

```
http://localhost/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/stylesheets/compass/css3/_font-face.scss
```

And I get 404:s for the files in Chrome's cobsole. This happens for the Compass core mixins I'm using, as well as the two extensions. Obviously that url is incorrect but I cannot figure out why it's pointing there. Seems like some configuration error somewhere.

My Gemfile:

```
# A sample Gemfile
source "https://rubygems.org"

# gem "rails"
gem 'sass', "3.4.10"
gem 'compass', "1.0.3"
gem 'compass-responsive-embeds', "0.0.4"
gem 'breakpoint',  "2.5.0"
```

My config.rb:

```
require 'compass/import-once/activate'
# require 'compass'

# Require any additional compass plugins here.
require 'breakpoint'
require 'compass-responsive-embeds'

# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "/"
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "i"
fonts_dir = "fonts"
javascripts_dir = "js"

relative_assets = true

sourcemap = (environment == :production) ? false : true
```